# Cannot use newer Dagger 2.11 API in Android

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am trying to import Dagger 2 into a brand new project on Android Studio and having a look at the various guides and documentation, I am unable to use `DaggerAppComponent`

My Gradle settings are as follows:

**build (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raywenderlich.todolist"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    //Dagger 2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

The in my `TodolistApplication.java` class: I have this:

```
      @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this);
  }
```

However Android Studio shows the following error:

> Error:(21, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

I have tried rebuilding the project and importing various `dagger` files, however nothing seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error:(21, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

The above error is not a dependency error.
AppComponent must be first created before using it like below

```
@Module public class ApplicationModule {
   //all dependency provides here
}

@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class) 
public interface ApplicationComponent {
}
```

Check this reference for complete understanding https://medium.com/@isoron/a-friendly-introduction-to-dagger-2-part-1-dbdf2f3fb17b

Comment: Thanks for that. It solved some of my issues, DaggerAppComponent is now working, however, the compiler is not picking up the '.application(this)' part of that code. Another ) error: cannot find symbol method application(ToDoListApplication) - I feel I am missing something small here.

Comment: Okay, never mind. I found the error. It was a missing method in my AppComponent class. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tander You should add this method to your `ApplicationComponent`. Did you copy code from some tutorial?

Comment: @DeKaNszn that was my mistake. Still trying to figure out Dagger as a whole.